# First accordion panel open

Tags: javascript, php, html, accordion

I can't seem to work out how to get my first accordion panel to open automatically. Problem is, I can't set it to active as it is displaying data with PHP from a database so if I set the div to "active-panel" it applies it to all the panels. Any help would be great! Just to clarify, I'm just trying to get the first one to open automatically. Code:

```
$('.panel-holder').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.accordion').find('.panel-holder').removeClass('active-panel');
        $(this).addClass('active-panel');
```

**PHP**

```
echo "<div class='panel-holder'>

    <div class='panel-title'>". $results['job_title'] ."
        <i class='icon arrow_carrot-down'></i>
    </div>

    <div class='panel-content'>
        <p class='lead'>". $results['job_summary'] ."</p>
        <p>". $results['job_description'] ."</p>
    </div>

    </div><!--end of individual accordian panel-->";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the "active-panel" class to the first item in PHP only. Are those generated in a loop? Just create a counter variable that increases in every run of the loop. If this counter == 1 (or 0 if you want to start with 0 ;) ) add the css class to your markup.

Comment: Thanks @Markus Müller! Unfortunately my PHP skills aren't good enough to manage that. I was kind of hoping there would be some kind of simple `panel-holder:first` css solution. Haha

Comment: Well this might work, too. Add a wrapper around your panel-holders. The first one should be accessible by 

    #wrapper div.panel-holder:firstchild

But my PHP is far better than my CSS ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a go. Wish my PHP was better than my CSS. Unfortunately they're about the same and that's not saying much for either ;) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating the following solution:

```
$('.panel-holder').each(function () {
        $(this).closest('.accordion').find('.panel-holder:first').addClass('active-panel');

    });
```